Gz Harmonic - Is there a Lidar sensor that is meant to be used on a machine without GPU?
I am looking for a Lidar Sensor in Gazebo Harmonic which is meant to be used on a machine without GPU. Is there one?

I found from here that the same mightn't exist. But then I found a Lidar.cc file in gz-sensors github repo in addition to the GPULidar.cc file. Is this supposed to be a CPU-based Lidar sensor?
I went ahead & tried inserting the following sensor tag as part of my world's .sdf file but the gz transport topics didn't get published.

<sensor type="lidar" name="lidar">
  <topic>/lidar</topic>
  <lidar>
    <scan>
      <horizontal>
        <samples>50</samples>
        <resolution>1</resolution>
        <min_angle>-0.75</min_angle>
        <max_angle>0.75</max_angle>
      </horizontal>
      <vertical>
        <samples>50</samples>
        <resolution>1</resolution>
        <min_angle>-0.55</min_angle>
        <max_angle>0.55</max_angle>
      </vertical>
    </scan>
    <range>
      <min>0.2</min>
      <max>1.8</max>
      <resolution>0.001</resolution>
    </range>
  </lidar>
  <update_rate>5</update_rate>
  <visualize>true</visualize>
  <always_on>1</always_on>
</sensor>


However I switched <sensor type="lidar" ...> to <sensor type="gpu_lidar" ...> and the transport topics got published.

Note:
I found this tutorial uses a gpu_lidar sensor when it had to explain how to use a lidar sensor.
Thanks in advance!

The Lidar.cc version publishes a gz::msgs::LaserScan message. Therefore it simulates a planar laser range-finder while the GPULidar.cc version publishes a gz::msgs::PointCloudPacked message. Thus the GPULidar.cc version allows you to simulate a LiDAR with multiple layers (N-dimensional points).
If you want to use a cpu-based LiDAR that publishes a gz::msgs::PointCloudPacked message, you should probably follow this advice for now.
Since the Lidar.cc and GPULidar.cc version are simulating different variants of LiDARs you cannot subscribe to both topics with the same code (due to different message types). You might also check the logs of Gazebo to see if there is some output why it might not be able to publish the topic.

What type do I include in the <sensor type=""> tag to use the Lidar.cc file? I tried  <sensor type="lidar" but that's not working. I'm checking the published gz transport topics using gz topic -l & no lidar topic shows up. I'm not using any code. Just the said CLI.

Using lidar as type is correct. Check your logs to see if there is anything about the LiDAR sensor.

I get this msg: [Wrn] [SdfEntityCreator.cc:963] Sensor type LIDAR not supported yet. Try usinga GPU LIDAR instead. GPU LIDAR does publishes 2 topics of which one is of typeLaserScan & the other is PointCloudPacked. So maybe I have to just use the 1st topic.

Alright the SdfEntityCreator.cc:963 file notes \todo(anyone) Implement CPU-based lidar. Therefore following the advice I referred to in my answer seems to be the only option at the moment.
